# can I run "Google Chrome" from terminal with arguments to fill the username and password?

Tags: macos, shell, google-chrome, command-line

I know that we can run the Google Chrome browser from command line:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" "http://myurl"
```

I want to open a page with a form to fill the username and password. Can I pass the username and password in command line to automatically fill?

Or it is impossible? Thanks

I'm using Mac.

Comment: [`--profile-directory` switch](http://superuser.com/q/377186/376602)? Link to [all Google Chrome switches](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc?view=markup).

Comment: hey @chipbk10, did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
open --new -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args "http://google.com"
```